# ¿Cómo omitir en expresiones regulares un caracter que está en medio de otros dos?

Tags: php, regex

En *expresiones regulares* ¿Cómo omitir un caracter que está en medio de otros dos?

Ejemplo: Si quisiera reemplazar `x` en una cadena, pero que este `x` no esté en medio de `e` y `p`.

```
<?php
    $x=3;
    $cadena= 'exp(x,2)';
?>
```

El primer caracter, `x`, quiero que sea ignorado, es decir, que me reemplace todas las `x` que aparezcan si no están entre `e` y `p`.

La idea es reemplazar la variable `x` dentro del texto de la ecuación por el valor de la variable `$x` en mi script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Opción 1: Reemplazar x como palabra completa

Viendo que estás intentando reemplazar las `x` de una ecuación, quizás es más sencillo no complicarse por qué está antes o después, y reemplazar aquellas que son una palabra completa. `\b` coincide con *posiciones* en [límites de palabras completas](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php) (*[word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*). Es decir, que este regex sólo va a coincidir con las `x` que son palabras completas (que no están precedidas ni sucedidas por caracteres de palabras -letras, números o guiones bajos).

```
/\bx\b/
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FT4fnB/1/)</kbd>

#### Opción 2: Inspecciones - que no esté precedida y no esté sucedida

Una opción directa de obtener lo que estás buscando es utilizando [inspecciones](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php) (*[lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*). La siguiente expresión coincide con:

- una `x`, que no esté seguida por:

  - una posición precedida por `ex`,
  - y una `p`.

```
/x(?!(?<=ex)p)/
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GLwSmu/1/)</kbd>

```php
$regex = '/x(?!(?<=ex)p)/';

$x=3;
$cadena= 'exp(x,2) - ext(axp * exp)';

$resultado = preg_replace($regex, $x, $cadena);

echo 'Resultado: ' . $resultado;
//=>  Resultado: exp(3,2) - e3t(a3p * exp)
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/v9wYLL)</kbd>

#### Opción 3: Coincidir con las excepciones, pero no reemplazarlas

Una opción menos intuitiva, pero mucho más práctica, es también coincidir con `exp`, pero crear una captura con un [grupo](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) (o subpatrón; *[capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)*).

```
/(exp)|x/
```

Y, usando una función como callback al momento de reemplazar, sólo modificarlo si el grupo 1 no capturó nada.

```php
$regex = '/(exp)|x/';

$x = 3;
$cadena = 'exp(x,2) - ext(axp * exp)';

$reemplazo = function ($matches) use ($x) {
    if (isset($matches[1])) //capturó en grupo 1, entonces, devolver el mismo valor (no reemplazar)
        return $matches[1];
    return $x;              //reemplazar por el valor que se quiera
};

$resultado = preg_replace_callback($regex, $reemplazo, $cadena);

echo 'Resultado: ' . $resultado;
//=>  Resultado: exp(3,2) - e3t(a3p * exp)
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/Ow1Ymx)</kbd>

#### Opción 4: Usar verbos de control

Con `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` ([*control verbs*](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html)), se fuerza un fallo en el intento de coincidencia y se avanza a la posición del string en la que se encuentra actualmente.

```
/exp(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|x/
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j5igCO/1/)</kbd>

Comment: me disculpo contigo, ya me di cuenta que al momento de copiar el código se me fue esa letra, todo funciona a la perfección .